# Funciones en js

Tags: funciones

El siguiente código lanza un error en la consola del navegador

```
sayHello(firstName, lastName){
 
let msg = "Greetings ";
 
function intro(){
 
return
 
msg + firstName = " " + lastName;
 
}
 return into();
}
sayHello("Professor" , "Falken");
 
//returns "Greetings Professor Falken";
```

Tras la líneas del comentario se encuentra lo que debiese salir . No obstante se declara un error , que indica que la primera llave es un token inesperado. Necesito una explicación para corregir el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores en ese código.

El primero es que declaras la función llamada `intro` pero luego al llamarla lo haces con el nombre `into`.

El segundo error es la manera en la que estás intentando crear el mensaje.

La manera correcta de hacerlo es así: `msg = msg + firstName + " " + lastName;`

Osea, ahí le dices que el nuevo valor de `msg` debe ser lo que actualmente tiene `msg` ("Greetings ") concatenado con `firstName` luego con el espacio (" ") y por último con el `lastName`.

El tercer error, como ya te dijeron, es que le falta la palabra `function` a `sayHello`.

Esto es importante, ya que al declarar una función siempre hay que usar la palabra `function` o en su defecto el arrow function `() => {}`. Luego al llamar a la función ahí sí que no es necesario agregar eso y llamas a la función solo con su nombre y los paréntesis.

El cuarto y último error, que también ya te marcaron, es asegurarte de poner lo que quieras retornar en una función siempre al lado del `return`, nunca abajo. Si no, al ponerlo abajo, con el `return` terminarás devolviendo un valor `undefined`.

Ejecuta el siguiente código ya corregido y verás el resultado que estabas esperando:

```js
function sayHello(firstName, lastName){
 
  let msg = "Greetings ";

  function intro(){

    return msg = msg + firstName + " " + lastName;

  }
  return intro();
}


document.write(sayHello("Professor" , "Falken"))
//returns "Greetings Professor Falken";
```

PD: Considera marcar una respuesta como "aceptada" en caso de que esta te haya sido útil. Eso servirá para que otros que tengan problemas similares al tuyo sepan que una respuesta es efectiva. [Aquí se explica cómo  hacerlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta , ha servido una enormidad

Answer (score 1):

te falta indicar "function":

```
sayHello(firstName, lastName){
```

deberia ser:

```
function sayHello(firstName, lastName){
```

esta parte no devolvera nada porque estas poniendo un return vacio antes de realizar ninguna operacion.

```
function intro(){


return


msg + firstName = " " + lastName;}
```

un ejemplo para hacer lo que propones de un modo mas simple seria:

```
function sayHello(firstName, lastName){
   return 'Greetings ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

espero haberte ayudado,

saludos.

Comment: Al probar tu codigo aparece undefined

Comment: faltaria llamar a la funcion, por ejemplo como han puesto mas abajo.

Comment: Claro si . Añadí un console.log e imprime igual que la recomendación dada más abajo. Muy útil tu respuesta gracias